# I can't get quick.db working without errors

Tags: npm, npm-scripts

I installed quick.db it shows up in my package.json file, but when I try linking to it with:

```js
const db = require('quick.db');
```

it gives me this error:

> ```
> C:\Users\My PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:135
>  throw err;
>  ^
>
> Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
> ```

When I remove the line above the bot runs. How can I fix this?

The full error is shown below:

> ```
> C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\bindings\bindings.js:135
>  throw err;
>  ^
>
> Error: Could not locate the bindings file. Tried:
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Debug\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\Release\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\out\Debug\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\Debug\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\out\Release\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\Release\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\build\default\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\compiled\12.18.1\win32\x64\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\release\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\debug\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\addon-build\default\install-root\better_sqlite3.node
> → C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\better-sqlite3\lib\binding\node-v72-win32-x64\better_sqlite3.node
>    at bindings (C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\[4mbindings[24m\bindings.js:126:9)
>    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\[4mbetter-sqlite3[24m\lib\database.js:6:40)
> [90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
> [90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
> [90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
> [90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
> [90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)[39m
> [90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)[39m
>    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Sammy's PC\Documents\Discord Bots\Discord Bot Files\node_modules\[4mbetter-sqlite3[24m\lib\index.js:2:18)
> [90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m {
>   tries: [
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\out\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\Debug\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\out\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\Release\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\build\\default\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\compiled\\12.18.1\\win32\\x64\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\release\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\debug\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\addon-build\\default\\install-root\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m,
>     [32m"C:\\Users\\Sammy's PC\\Documents\\Discord Bots\\Discord Bot Files\\node_modules\\better-sqlite3\\lib\\binding\\node-v72-win32-x64\\better_sqlite3.node"[39m
>   ]
> }
> ```